# What is the meaning of joke "may it plizzle the cozizzle" in Futurama?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

In [Futurama 5ACV16](http://theinfosphere.org/Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder_Part_4), character Leela, while in court, says "May it plizzle the cozizzle" instead of "may it please the court" to the judge ([Snoop Dogg's head](http://theinfosphere.org/Snoop_Dogg%27s_head)).

I am not native English speaker, but I understand it is supposed to be funny. One part of being funny is the fact that wrong expression is used in the courtroom. However, I feel there is also some English language aspect of this being funny.

So, why is it funny? What is "cozizzle"? Is there some cultural context of this joke I am missing?

Is it funny because "plizzle" rhymes with "cozizzle", and "cozizzle" mimics some words from the Snoop Doggs songs? Which words? I searched his lyrics, found nothing relevant. Googling "cozizzle" finds nothing relevant as well. Is it supposed to mimic ethnical slang?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Maybe they put the script through http://www.gizoogle.net/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Is there some cultural context of this joke I am missing?

Yes.

> Is it funny because "plizzle" rhymes with "cozizzle", and "cozizzle" mimics some words from the Snoop Doggs songs?

Yes as well.  Snoop Dogg popularized the slang (in black culture in the US) of adding the -izzle suffix (and sometimes infix) to various words.  He does it in many songs, including [*Drop It Like It's Hot*](https://genius.com/Snoop-dogg-drop-it-like-its-hot-lyrics) and [*Tha Shiznit*](https://genius.com/Snoop-dogg-tha-shiznit-lyrics).  He also does it as a guest in other rappers' songs, such as the intro to Dr. Dre's [*The Chronic*](https://genius.com/Dr-dre-the-chronic-intro-lyrics).

The -izzle suffix, however, existed long before Snoop Dogg more or less made it famous.  It was originally "used by African American pimps and jive hustlers of the 1970s," according to the Wiktionary article to which I will link.

Check out the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-izzle) article on the matter, and do a Google search for *snoop dogg izzle* to get lots of info.

Comment: Thanks. I also located it in [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=izzle)

Comment: Feel free to markizzle this shizzle as accepted if it works for rizzle.

Comment: When controversy arose over plagiarism in Dogg's songs, it went to the English High Court, leading to what I consider the best ever opening to a written judgment: "There is something peculiar about a system in which three men in wigs and gowns spend days discussing the exact meaning of the words "Drizzle on my nizzle"."

Comment: @TimLymington 

Comment: @TimLymington Awesome find, do you have a link to some documentation about that? Would love a read

Comment: @FlorianPeschka "This led to the faintly surreal experience of three gentlemen in horsehair wigs examining the meaning of such phrases as “mish mish man” and “shizzle (or sizzle) my nizzle”." [Confetti-Records-v-Warner-Music.pdf](http://www.5rb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Confetti-Records-v-Warner-Music-ChD-23-May-2003.pdf)

Answer (score 20):

While other answers have been correct in identifying Snoop Dogg's popularization of the term, I think some explanation on the actual joke may be of use to you as well.

As you already spotted, "If it plizzles the cozizzle" is meant as a Snoop Dogg-style translation of "If it pleases the court".

Keep in mind that Futurama is set in the future. The fact Leela uses that statement in an actual court, and no one even laughs or objects, points towards that being the correct thing to say in the year 3000.

If we hear Shakespearean English today, it sounds haughty. As the only people still occupied with the older versions of English (or traditional pronunciations) generally are. Its historical context (and contrast by using it today) also carries a connotation of intellectualism.
However, during Shakespeare's day, that was the *lingua franca*, i.e. how everybody spoke. It was normal, maybe even considered vulgar dialect (as the actual upper class at that point spoke Latin/French (not sure for English history, to be honest)).

According to Futurama's joke, the same has happened to the izzle-speak. It used to be a lingua franca/vulgar way of speaking *to us*, but over time, it was regarded as more historical, and in turn more intelligent.

If it stands to reason that past languages sound overly haughty to us, it must stand to reason that the people in the year 3000 regard our historical (to them) izzle-speak to sound haughty.

Comment: The actual upper class in Shakespeare's time (late 16th and early 17th centuries) often did know Latin and French. Queen Elizabeth certainly did. Furthermore, Latin was and still is used in some ceremonial contexts and in the Church. But they habitually spoke English to each other. *Lingua franca* doesn't mean "how everyone / common people speak", it means a language in common spoken by those who don't necessarily share a native tongue. It's Italian, referring literally to French (which was the language of international discourse and diplomacy), then to any language with that role.

Comment: Speaking of Church use, it was during the reign of Elizabeth's father, Henry VIII, that William Tyndale became the first to print the Bible in English. The inability of the uneducated masses to access scripture, since it was available only in Latin, could reasonably be described as "a major political issue" at the time ;-) Not that the uneducated masses could *read* English themselves, but being read to in Latin was competely wasted on them. Tyndale was executed for heresy in Flanders. Henry later also published an English bible.

Comment: Lingua franca can also be used as a "people's language". I originally learned of the word during Latin class, as *Greek* was the Romans' lingua franca (meaning it was how people in daily life communicated), whereas Latin was the more official language. I also assumed English upper class spoke French, due to the duality between words like chicken/poultry, cow/beef, lamb/veal, ...

Comment: As a Flemishman myself, I apologize for the execution ;) Also to note, didn't Shakespeare specifically write plays for the masses, as opposed to for the upper class? That would confirm the language he used adhered more to what the lower classes could understand, not the upper class. Making it more vulgar or everyday than it sounds to us now.

Comment: Following the Norman conquest, yes the nobility did speak French habitually until some time around the late 14th century. I forget which kings spoke what languages and to whom, but basically over the course of the Hundred Years War, the English nobility felt it both patriotic and wise to become English as opposed to French!

Comment: Oh. correction to what I said earlier. The phrase "lingua franca" is indeed Italian, but "franca" means "Frankish" not "French". It didn't originally refer to French, rather to the mixed trade language of the Mediterranean. French was indeed used as an international language later, but it's not the eponymous *lingua franca*.

Comment: I always assumed it's origin is related to that of the English "being *frank*", as it implies it's not the most polite way of phrasing something, but at least it can be understood. We still use the word "frank" in Dutch to mean the same.

Comment: dictionary.com tells me that the adjective "frank" meaning outspoken or uninhibited, is from Latin "francus", free, whereas the noun Frank, referring to a germanic tribe eventually located in what is now France, probably isn't from the same root but might be from a Germanic root word "franka", a spear/javelin. Knowing the history and prejudices of my race, the notion of deriving a word meaning "open and honest" from a word for the French seems unlikely, but stranger things have happened ;-)

Comment: Given how the Romans were involved with the barbaric tribes in Western Europe, it's a possible explanation that's why "francus" means "free" in Latin as opposed to "civilized" (as "barbaric" carried a similar connotation for the Romans). But I'd need to do some research to confirm the link.

Comment: Mmm wiktionary doesn't even have "free" as a Latin meaning of "francus", it just means "Frankish" according to them. Actually I misread dictionary.com, it gives "free" as "Late Latin" and there the etymology stops without going back to classical Latin. So you're probably right.

Comment: Again, I think it boils down to a very similar idea. Tribes are often referenced as "free people" (meaning the civilized law doesn't apply to them), and "speaking frankly" is in essence "speaking freely". In any form you encounter "frank", it seems to always express the same idea of functionality over politeness, or as a more direct approach using blunt honesty. Which is almost exactly how Caesar and a lot of Romans regarded the Gauls. They respected them as a people but noted how uncivilized they were according to Roman standards.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia says the Mediterranean trade language was called "franca" because in Greek after the division of the Roman Empire, anyone west of Greece was all just "phrankoi". So another case of all barbarians being the same.

Comment: The language of the plays was intended to be comprehensible to the common people, but most of it was written metrically in a way common speech would not have been.  Much of the dialogue is written with a form of metrical line, groups of consecutive lines have AABB or ABAB patterns of matching or related word stresses (not just having the same number of metrical feet, but the same patterns of stronger and weaker stresses).  Not all performances capture that nuance, but it's clearly present in many places and not coincidental.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Futurama lampshaded precisely this language drift in the series with regards to the pronunciation of 'ask' as 'axe'.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0584465/quotes?item=qt1592138

Comment: Shakespeare wrote for a variety of audiences. The company in which he was a shareholder in fact maintained two theatres--a large and relatively cheap open-air theatre in the summer for popular audiences, and a much smaller and more expensive indoor theatre in the winter for sophisticated audiences. And they frequently played at the royal court as well; after his accession King James himself was their official sponsor.